# Why do I have more flags available?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flagging

When I was going to flag a question, this is what came up. Pay attention to the flag count at the bottom-right.
[image: flag error]

I thought that users received only 10 flags per day. Has this policy been changed (probably not) or is there some other bug that is causing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The base amount of flags per day is ten but you get more per day as a reward for having more reputation or good flagging history - up to 100 total flags per day.

If you read the [flagging privilege page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) a bit more closely you'll see it says all the way down at the bottom:

> ### How many flags do I have?
>
> When you start out, you are allotted 10 flags per day. This number may increase to up to 100 flags per day:
>
> - You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
> - You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags).

You have 13 net helpful post flags, so you get one extra flag per day - 11 total.

No bugs here.

Comment: If you have -10 or less net helpful flags can you lose flags?

Comment: @Stormblessed - You start out with ten flags a day. Since you can't have a *negative* number of helpful flags, that number doesn't go down. However, with enough declined flags - 10% of all your post flags handled in a seven day period, I believe - you will get flag-banned for about a week.

Comment: @Mithrandir oh, it seems to be if there are three declined in the list it sends you to you get flag-banned from my experience.

Comment: @Stormblessed [details are here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/278659)

Comment: Huh... so that's how I got 59 flags. :-P